# Form/Query couple stops working once embedded in another Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

[Working in MS Access 2019 Professional Plus 2019. Not that it matters though.]
My setup can be narrowed down to this hierarchy, which works perfectly fine on its own :

```
'------> Hierarchy of objects :

"myMainForm" contains :
    "select_client" (ComboBox based on "client" table)
    "select_status" (ComboBox based on "status" table)
    ' and some multi-select checkboxes that forbid use of Master/Child feature
    "mySubForm" 
        "Source Object" : "myQuery" ' "mySubForm" not saved with an explicit name, local to "myMainForm"

"mQuery" filters the table "course" :
    "client_ID" criteria : [Forms]![myMainForm]![select_client]
    "status_ID" criteria : [Forms]![myMainForm]![select_status]

'------> "myMainForm" VBA to requery on change (could be performed with Macros) :

Private Sub select_client_Change()
    Me!mySubForm.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub select_status_Change()
    Me!mySubForm.Requery
End Sub
```

Then I try to embed "myMainForm" in a higher level form (let's say "myNavForm") :

```
"myNavForm" contains :
    "myMainForm" contains :
        ' same as above from there
        "mySubForm"
```

When I try to run `"myNavForm"`, I get prompted for `[Forms]![myMainForm]![select_client]` and `[Forms]![myMainForm]![select_status]`, and `"myMainForm"` stops working entirely.

I first thought the problem was related to the ComboBox values not being loaded yet when `"myQuery"` is triggered, so I added the following VBA to `"myMainForm"` :

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me!mySubForm.SourceObject = "Query.myQuery"
    Me!mySubForm.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Me!mySubForm.SourceObject = ""
End Sub
```

But the problem remains the same. I guess it comes from a scope / path mistake on my side, but I can't figure it out. I tried absolute paths in `"myQuery"` as you can see above. I also tried using relative paths with `.Parent` but couldn't make `"myMainForm"` to work with it (without even embedding in `"myNavForm"`).

Therefore, I am stuck and screwed and desperate and I want my Node/MongoDB environment back, but I have to do this in Access (don't ask !).

Any idea how to make it work with embedding ? As much as possible, I'd prefer sticking to that setup and avoid entering more complex VBA (the syntax gives me headaches), but I'm open to it if needed ;-)

Thx for any kind of help to free me from that nightmare !

---

[EDIT : SOLUTION IN MY USE CASE BASED ON ACCEPTED ANSWER (for future readers !)]

Thanks to @Olivier , here is the solution working flawlessly :

```
'------> Hierarchy of objects :

"myMainForm" contains :
    "select_client" '(ComboBox based on "client" table)
    "select_status" '(ComboBox based on "status" table)
    "mySubForm" 
        "Source Object" : "myQuery" 'remove all criteria from the query !

' ------> Handle the rest in VBA :

'Lets write this only once...
Private Sub updateResult()
    mySubForm.Form.Filter = "client_ID=" & select_client & " AND status_ID=" & select_status
    mySubForm.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub

'Apply filter with default values upon loading
Private Sub mySubForm_Current()
    updateResult
End Sub

'Update filter whenever a control is updated
Private Sub select_client_AfterUpdate()
    updateResult
End Sub
Private Sub select_status_AfterUpdate()
    updateResult
End Sub
```

All in all, I finally have a nice framework to update any multi-criteria query on the fly after any control update and view the result immediately on the form, behaving just as any modern GUI should ! Thx again Olivier !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because then your `select_client` has another path. Now it is

```
[Forms]![myNavForm]![myMainForm].Form![select_status]
```

where `myMainForm` is now  a subform-control. It may have a different name than the contained form.

Instead of including such paths into the query, try to filter the subform like this

```
mySubForm.Form.Filter = "client_ID=" & select_client & " AND status_ID=" & select_status
mySubForm.Form.FilterOn = True
```

You would do so in the after update events of these two fields and on the form OnCurrent event.

Comment: Thx/Merci ! It works perfectly (after some time to refactor things) ! I just don't understand the need/meaning of `.FilterOn` after each filter change, and the need/meaning of the form `.Current` event handling (despite checking the documentation). Could you just precise those requirements and I will be forever thankful !?

Comment: The `Current` event is fired when the form has loaded a record (if the form is bound to a table or query). It just does the initial filtering. If the main form is not bound to records, you can omit this (unless the two filter fields have default values that have to be applied from start.). `FilterOn` allows you to enable or disable the filter. If it works without, just drop this line.

Comment: Ok ! Seems that `FilterOn` is not needed in my case [yet]. And I'll need `Current` to initialize the filter with my default values. Your answer is way better than originally planned, and allows me to get rid of the query when I need only one table ! Merci mille fois / Thx so much !

Comment: My bad, FilterOn is required ! Your answer was just outrageously on point :-) Updated my question to add complete solution for future readers